# Is it possible to get the apache server-status page without sending a GET request to one of the workers?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, perl

I have the server-status page setup and can access it through 
`http://localhost/server-status` and commands like `apache2ctl status`.

Is there a way to access the infromation in the server-status page or generating the information (maybe using mod_perl) without having to use an apache worker?

This will be particularly useful when apache2 is frozen e.g no workers are available for extended periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check:

- The service state with `journalctl -u apache2`
- The regular logs in `/var/log/apache2`
- The state of the memory, cpu, disk I/O, networktraffic with `ps`, `top`, `htop`, `ntop`, `iotop`  or even reading the dirs `/proc/PIDNUMMERS/` directly
- The portstates with `iptables`, `lsof` and `nmap`
- The traffic flowing from/to the server with `tcpdump` and `wireshark`

This should provide enough info about the status to keep you occupied for a while...

You can use a (perl)script to filter and combine all this info to get what you are really interested in.
But: the reason of the frozen pid's won't always be the same. By using a script you will miss important information, i strongly recommend to examine it manually.